# Stretch element to full width of a padded fluid parent

Tags: jquery, html, css, padding, fluid-layout

I can't explain this well so I made a diagram. Yay!

[image: sweet diagram bro]

I have a parent  that has a width of 95% and a padding of 30px. 99% of the elements inside this section will always be width 100% chilling out within the bounds of the padding.

BUT. I have one alternate use case in which an alert will pop up at the top of the section, that needs to stretch the WHOLE way across the page.

I could make an inner container that could hold most of the content but if theres a pretty no mess way where I could make that success banner have the width of 100% + padding and then offset it (I know I can position:relative that), then that seems like it would be the best solution.

Comment: You could also use a negative margin-left

Comment: Does `width: 100%; margin-left: -30px` work?

Comment: it's not the positioning that's a concern, but the width. width 100% will only stretch it within the padding. see: http://cl.ly/1O3E2t0c0r0p3P1a1A3Q

Comment: Ah yeah I see, I added an answer with a different solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `width: 100%`, try `display: block` and `margin: 0 -30px;` Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tx6av/1/ (sorry about the bad IDs)